# How to view data from xampp to jtable in Java Netbeans

Tags: java, netbeans, xampp

I would like to ask why the data of my database didn't show in Jtable. I think, I follow properly the tutorial I watched.

```
public ArrayList<helpdesk> gethelpdeskList()             
{
     ArrayList<helpdesk> HelpdeskList = new ArrayList<helpdesk>();
     Connection con = getConnection();
     String query = "SELECT * FROM `ithelpdesk`";
     Statement st;
     ResultSet rs;

     try {
            st = con.createStatement();
            rs = st.executeQuery(query);
            helpdesk ithelpdesk; 

            while(rs.next()) { 
                ithelpdesk = new helpdesk(rs.getInt("Trackerno"),rs.getInt("scode"), rs.getString("sconcern"), rs.getString("sremarks"), rs.getString("createdby"),rs.getString("assignedby"),rs.getString("status"));
            }           
        } catch (SQLException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(hdesktable.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }

        return HelpdeskList;
}  

public void show_record(){

    ArrayList<helpdesk> list = gethelpdeskList();
    DefaultTableModel model =(DefaultTableModel) jtable_helpdesk.getModel();

    Object[] row = new Object[7];
    for(int i = 0; i<list.size();i++)
    {
        row[0] = list.get(i).getTrackerno();
        row[1] = list.get(i).getscode();
        row[2] = list.get(i).getsconcern();
        row[3] = list.get(i).getsremarks();
        row[4] = list.get(i).getcreatedby();
        row[5] = list.get(i).assignedby();
        row[6] = list.get(i).status();
        model.addRow(row);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I assume that you are not getting any exceptions in your code. One problem can be that you are not adding "ithelpdesk" to "HelpdeskList" in the while loop.

Comment: how can I add the "ithelpdesk" ? Apology for this kind of question. I am totally beginner in programming.

Comment: HelpdeskList.add(ithelpdesk);